# I am getting error in eclipse after installed groovy plugin

Tags: groovy, eclipse-plugin, groovy-eclipse

I have installed groovy plugin in my Eclipse and I have changed the compiler to 2.4  as a job duty and restarted the eclipse then I am getting the error "Failed to create the part's controls".  Can anyone please help me?

Comment: Look in the .log file in the workspace .metadata directory to see if there is a more detailed message.

Answer (score 0):

Is this the problem you are seeing: https://github.com/groovy/groovy-eclipse/issues/317#issuecomment-316430547

This can be resolved by removing newer Groovy compiler versions.  In your case, you want to use Groovy 2.4, so remove 2.5 and 2.6/3.0 (if you have them installed).